# Retrieving both a 'count where' and and overall count simultaneously

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database of restaurant ratings and reviews, and for each restaurant there can be anywhere from 1 to about 1000 reviews.

I first tried to find which restaurants have the most 4+ rated reviews where the comment includes the word 'taco', and I got it working with the code below:

```
    select id, count(id) from test where (comment like '%taco%') AND rating >= 3 group by id order by count(id) DESC;
```

So for example, if restaurant X has thirty 4+ rated reviews that include 'taco', I would get 'X|30' for that line.

I want to add two additional features:

1. List the total number of reviews for each restaurant (without any conditions)
2. Give the average rating for all of a restaurant's reviews that include 'taco'.

If restaurant X has 150 total reviews, 30 of them are 4+ rated and include 'taco', and the average rating for those 30 reviews is 2.5, I would get:

'X|30|150|2.5|'

How do I get this result?

Comment: How can the average of 4+-rated reviews be 2.5?

Comment: Shouldn't 4+ ratings be `ratings >= 4`?

Comment: Good catch, bah.  I meant the average rating of all a restaurant's reviews that include 'taco' is 2.5.  So there are 30 4+ rated reviews and a lot of lower reviews.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this might work.

```
select id
, count(*) totalreviews
, sum(case when rating >= 3 and comment like '%taco%' then 1 else 0 end) ratings4plus
, avg(case when rating >= 3 and comment like '%taco%' then rating else null end) avgratings4plus
from test
group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but you might try something like

```
select id,
       count(id), 
       sum(case when (comment like '%taco%' and rating >=3) then 1 
                else 0 end) taco_rating, 
       avg(case when comment like '%taco%' then rating else null end ) avg_taco
  from test
 group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use subqueries:

```
SELECT id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM test
        WHERE id = t1.id
          AND comment LIKE '%taco%'
          AND rating >= 3),
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM test
        WHERE id = t1.id),
       (SELECT AVG(rating)
        FROM test
        WHERE id = t1.id
          AND comment LIKE '%taco%'
          AND rating >= 3),
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id
      FROM test) AS t1
```

Answer (score 1):

For `4+`, your test should be `rating > 3` rather than `rating >= 3`, but this will do it:

```
select
    id,
    sum(case when comment like '%taco%'
            AND rating > 3 then 1 else 0 end) as rating4plus_count,
    count(*) as all_ratings_count,
    avg(case when comment like '%taco%'
            AND rating > 3 then rating else null end) as rating4plus_avg
from test
group by id
order by 1 DESC;
```

Note the shorthand `order by 1`, which is the SQL standard way of ordering by "column number 1" (instead of repeating column 1's expression in the order by clause)